# How to tell node.js app environment supports styled/colored Console output?

Tags: node.js

I want to style Console output (`console.log('%cTest', 'color: lime')`) for debug purposes so I need to tell if script is running inside VSCode or not. Is it possible?

Clarification: I want "isomorphic" code which can detect if it's running inside VSCode and run colored console.log output or not in VSCode and run regular `console.log`.

Comment: You can run node yourfilename.js inside the terminal which comes with vscode if that's what you are asking. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @muhammad-kamran I want "isomorphic" code which can detect if it's running inside VSCode and run colored console.log output or not in VSCode and run regular console.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you need is detecting whether the console support color (and how well it supports color), not sniff whether the Node.js program is launched from VSCode.

To implement this requirement, npm module [supports-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supports-color) can be used:

```
// Code example taken from supports-color document

const supportsColor = require('supports-color');

if (supportsColor.stdout) {
    console.log('Terminal stdout supports color');
}

if (supportsColor.stdout.has256) {
    console.log('Terminal stdout supports 256 colors');
}

if (supportsColor.stderr.has16m) {
    console.log('Terminal stderr supports 16 million colors (truecolor)');
}
```

Comment: Actually, the code inside this module just check the platform and environment to figure out the support, not actually checking it.

Comment: Well, the `supports-color` module will check `process.env` (environment variables for current process), such as `FORCE_COLOR` or `COLORTERM` etc. I think it is the right thing to do (check current process details). The module does not sniff specific platform.

Comment: TBH, it does check if `win` platform: https://github.com/chalk/supports-color/blob/a4140d78478abca47a2015e300d283ea3d1e75ae/index.js#L68